# What can cause automapping to behave differently in different MVC app with same code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, http-post, automapper

I have a test app that works perfectly with the following classes in one app, but not in another:

```
public class ValueChange
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public List<ItemValueChange> Changes { get; set; }
}

public class ItemValueChange
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
}
```

My plugin posts a JS structure that matches this structure (`changes` is a jQuery array).

The raw post data (from Fiddler2) looks like:

```
GroupId 1000
Changes[0][Value]   
Changes[0][Key] 
Changes[0][ItemId]  1
```

In the test app this works and maps the data sent to a `ValueChange` object correctly.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Validate(ValueChange change)
    {
          // The Changes property has the required array of objects/properties
    }
```

In our main application, to which I just ported the plugin and classes, the post data sent looks like:

```
GroupId 3705
Changes[0][Value]   
Changes[0][Key] 
Changes[0][ItemId]  81866
```

and the validate method called looks identical:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Validate(ValueChange changes)
    {
         // changes contains a null list and no GroupId
    }
```

If I break-point this method changes is non-null object with a `GroupId` of 0 and no child elements in `Changes`. I can however see these values available from Request.Form in the debugger:

```
Request.Form["GroupId"] "3705"  string
Request.Form["Changes[0][Key]"] ""  string
Request.Form["Changes[0][ItemId]"]  "81866" string
Request.Form["Changes[0][Value]"]   ""  string
```

**Q. What would cause the automapping to not work in a different MVC project with the type of data?**

If I simplify `ValueChange` to this (below) it starts working and receives `GroupId` values:

```
public class ValueChange
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
}
```

If I send JS object data without a changes property it works e.g.

```
  { GroupId: 123 }
```

Something about the list called `Changes` is causing the mapping to fail. I have tried it as an array and also sending a single hard-wired entry from JS like this (still fails):

```
  { GroupId: 123, Changes: [{ItemId: 456, Value: "V", Key: "K"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

OMG. The auto-mapper **will ignore properties if a property name matches the parameter name**!!!

It was caused simply by having the parameter called `changes` (vs. `change` in the test app) when a property of the received data was also called changes.

Solution: I changed the parameter name e.g.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Validate(ValueChange valueChange)
{
}
```

To clarify, this problem occurs is a first-level property of the data passed matches a parameter name. If it were a nested property tit would not attempt to match the parameter name.

This little detail needs to be stapled to everyone's desk/hand/head.* :)

Comment: +1 for posting your solution! Sometimes it happens! :)